# html 'required' on form not working in gmail

Tags: html, forms, required

I have a form embedded onto an email that ask the user for input. The problem is, without proper check, they can submit an empty form.

```
<input class="name" type="text" name="name" required style="color: #000;width:99%;padding-left:3px;height:33px;font-size:1em;border:solid 1px #dbddde;font-weight:lighter;font-family: helvetica;border-radius:5px"><br>
```

As you can see I put the 'required' after the name value, it works when I test it in my browser but not when the email is sent out. Gmail strip away the 'required' portion and the user is still able to submit an empty form.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't much you can do, almost every client removes the required attribute. Why do you need a form input in an email? It seems kinda weird. I think you'll have to validate your inputs server-side.

Comment: We ask our customer to review the products they buy, seem like I need to find another way then.

Comment: If a rating from 0 to 5 is enough you could just have the five stars somewhere in the mail and when they click you load a "Thank you" page with the product id and any other thing you need as a get parameter.

Comment: What I ended up doing is just embedded the html thank you page under an if/else, if the form is empty then the data won't be inserted into the db and an error message showed up.